# Laravel 5.4 save json to database

Tags: php, json, laravel

help me with save json to db. Table field type - text. 
I have Model with cast array

```
class Salesteam extends Model 
{
    protected $casts = [        
        'team_members' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

I want get json like this {"index":"userId"} and store it to db.
Example:

```
{"1":"7","2":"14","3":"25","4":"11"}
```

I have Salesteam Model and 'team_members' column in db to saving all user id's belong to this team. 
My code find team by id, get all 'team_members' attribute and add new user to this team. I want store all users in json format and incrementing index when add new user id.

Salesteam attributes:

```
"id" => 20
"salesteam" => "Admin"
"team_leader" => 0
"invoice_target" => 884.0
"invoice_forecast" => 235.0
"team_members" => "[1,66,71]"
"leads" => 0
"quotations" => 0
"opportunities" => 0
"notes" => ""
"user_id" => 1
"created_at" => "2017-09-22 09:13:33"
"updated_at" => "2017-09-22 13:10:25"
"deleted_at" => null
```

Code to add new user to team:

```
$salesTeam = $this->model->find($salesTeamId);
$teamMembers = $salesTeam->team_members;
$teamMembers[] = $userId;
$salesTeam->team_members = $teamMembers;
$salesTeam->save();
```

But it stores to db array and without index

```
"team_members" => "[1,34,56]"
```

From Laravel documentation - [Array & JSON Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators) "array will automatically be serialized back into JSON for storage"

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add more specific detail ? What your code does ? and in which variable or line of code you are getting which output ?

Comment: Encode it to JSON before you save it?

Answer (score 4):

To make a json string like this

```
{"1":"7","2":"14","3":"25","4":"11"}
```

In `php`, you must pass a key, when you're pushing elements to array. e.g.

```
$teamMembers = [];
$teamMembers['1'] = 7;
$teamMembers['2'] = 14;
...
```

If you don't make it an `associative array`, `php` will consider it as json array when converting to json string..

**Tip:** You may pass only one key and it will work too.
e.g.

```
$test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$test['10'] = 56;

echo json_encode($test);
```

**Output:**

```
"{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6,"10":56}"
```

[PHP-Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-notes)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
$teamMembers = json_encode($salesTeam->team_members);
```

That should do be all.

Answer (score 0):

if you get this  `"[1,34,56]"` just do `json_decode($team_members)`

and you will have this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 34
  2 => 56
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

```
$books = App\Book::all();
$user->books = $books->toJson();
$user->save(); //example: userid -> 2

$user = App\User::find(2);
$userBooks = json_decode($user->books, true); // to generate object again
```