# Laravel 6.x PostgreSQL Insert Problem ? SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 Error

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

**System Info**

Laravel Framework 6.2

PHP 7.4 with XAMPP

PostgreSQL 12

pgAdmin 4

***Details***

Data deletion is working.

Data update is working.

but I can't create. :(

**Error Screenshots**

[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8DCt.png)

**yetkilerController.php**

```
function create(yetkilerRequest $request){

    $new = new yetkiler;
    $new->yetki_name = $request->yetki_name;
    $new->yetkiler = json_encode($request->yetkiler);
    $new->save();

    return redirect(route('users.yetkiler'))->with('success','Yetki başarıyla oluşturuldu !');

}
```

**create_yekilers_table.php**

```
Schema::create('yetkilers', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('yetki_name',100)->unique();
  $table->text('yetkiler');
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

**pgAdmin 4 Screenshots**

[Table Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bjfN.png)

[Table Dependents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imDUE.png)

Comment: It looks like you try to set incorrect data type into your column. Try to change you migration with `$table->json('yetkiler');` instead of `$table->text('yetkiler');`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364906/laravel-5-4-save-json-to-database

Comment: not related to json